# Cleanup unused blobs in filestorage in Plone

Tags: plone, zodb, blobstorage

Is there a way to find and remove unused blob storage space in a Plone site?

I'm looking for something like `bin/zeopack`, but that detects unused blobs in the `blobstorage` directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ZODB takes care of unused blobs by itself. Packing will remove blobs together with removed transactions as required.