# how to cleanly remove plone.app.imaging scaled blobs in a blobstorage ZEO server?

Tags: plone, dexterity, blobstorage

Part of this question is already solved with [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938983) but it seems that it doesn't clean up everything.

The steps are:

- create a document with an image field
- see that the blobstorage has **one** file
- open a view with a scaled version of that image
- see that the blobstorage now has *two* files, the image and the scaled image
- do, as suggested on the other question, a `zeopack` with **0 days**
- see that there is still **one blob** on blobstorage, the scaled image

So the question is: how can one remove also this scaled images from blobstorage?

I tried running `zeopack` twice without success, the scaled blob is still around.

**UPDATE:** as `vangheem` pointed out, that does not happen for Archetypes `Image` content types. Still, this question remains valid, as for a Dexterity-based content types that have an image field.

The scales are only removed if you remove the document, which is not my use-case, I just want to remove the image (image credits have expired and the image can not be shown anymore).

Comment: Why would you want to? The scaled images are used all over plone and would just get re-generated.

Comment: vangheem: the thing is that in our website we use images that have a certain expiration date (they are bought at getty or so). So **after** that expiration date they must be deleted, and obviously the scaled images are no longer needed nor will show up anywhere

Comment: Martijn: I just deleted the image field of the document. Maybe that's not the correct way of deleting an image field? As for the steps, they are exactly like I said on the question: create, add an image, make sure there are two blobs and then delete the image. After all this (the document is still there) I do the packing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!

To remove the scales you actually have to remove the plone.scale annotation:

```py
# assume 'document' is a Dexterity-based content type that has a NamedBlobImage field 
from zope.annotation.interfaces import IAnnotations
annotations = IAnnotations(document)
if 'plone.scale' in annotations:
    del annotations['plone.scale']
if getattr(document, 'image', None) is not None and document.image is not None:
    del document.image
    document.reindexObject()
```

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the content item should delete its scales also.

I just testing in plone 4.2.4. Here were my steps:

1. delete existing blobstorage and filestorage
2. start up plone
3. create new site
4. add image, see that 2 blobstorage files are created. One the original, another the one scale that has been created so far
5. delete the image, both files are still in blobstorage for undo support
6. pack the database to 0 days, both files are now removed from blobstorage

So everything seems to be working correctly.

In your post you mention that you're creating a document. If you means News Item, those images aren't stored in blobstorage.

Now, if you have a custom content type where you have an image field and you're just trying to delete the image field and the scales generated from that field, but not delete the entire type, you'll need to delete the scales manually. I think it'll be something like this:

```
del doc.__blob_scales['image']['preview']
```

Comment: It's a custom dexterity content type that has a NamedBlobImage  that comes from a behavior. But doing a ``hasattr(article, blobScalesAttr)`` fails. I see the scales on a annotation though ``IAnnotations(article)['plone.scale']``. That's  because is a dexerity based content type?

Comment: Seems that this ``__blob_scales`` is only there for Archetypes content types, but not for Dexterity (creating and ``Image`` content type does have it, but a TTW Dexterity content type with an image field does not)